# Test case sometime freezes for sometime on one machine

Tags: javascript, selenium, npm, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to run tests on two different machines, one is local running ubuntu 19.04 and other is centOS 7. Both using same configuration except for that centOS is running chrome on headless, no-sandbox, disable-gpu mode. 
On both machines tests pass normally as intended, but on centOS one of three cases sometimes freezes and instead of running < 1min it runs for >2 min. 
While test is running I get my message 'Clicked on Payments Tab, Now Loading' so I assume that .waitForElementVisible('.payments', load_speed)
has something to do with this

I tried to update all packages including nightwatch, chromedriver, selenium-server. Also tried changing some code.

```
payments: function() {
  return this
    .waitForElementVisible('#nav', load_speed, function(res) {
      if(res.value) {
        this.moveToElement('.more', 2, 2)
        .mouseButtonClick(0)
        .pause(2500)
        this.moveToElement('#other-menu > div:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)', 2, 2)
        .mouseButtonClick(0)
        console.log('Clicked on Payments Tab, Now Loading')
        this.waitForElementVisible('.payments', load_speed)
    } else { console.log('navigation bar or Payments tab does not exist')}
  })
},
```

Test should pass in ~1minute but instead it freezes as I specified in problem description and hangs there for that additional minute and passes test case in ~2minutes.
Good: OK. 16 assertions passed. (56.782s)
Bad:  OK. 16 assertions passed. (2m 29s / 149440ms)

Comment: Does it freeze or is it just slow? Different browsers on different OS's can have different rendering times.

Comment: I have 3 test cases in one suite. They are all must go through same navigation bar to press on object. And sometimes on always the same object it becomes stuck and waits there for like 1.5minute.